# Maven doesn't compile the project with jNativeHook from Github

Tags: java, maven, github, pom.xml, jnativehook

I have added Jitpack repo and dependency from Github to pom.xml and it still doesn't compile. However, when I point onto the line in import block, it clearly shows the description of a module.
[VSCode screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jatsO.png)

For example, I try to import com.github.kwhat.jnativehook.GlobalScreen, it shows the description of the module but still underlines the line with red and shows the error:

*The type com.github.kwhat.jnativehook.GlobalScreen is not accessible Java(16778666)*

What could be the problem?

Here's a part of **pom.xml**

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jitpack.io</id>
        <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.kwhat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jnativehook</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try to synchronize you project.

I add an imagine where can be seen that dependencies is load correctly.[image].

Comment: How can I sync it? Is it a command in a terminal or just an order for lines in pom.xml?
I tried to compile the project and I get an error in a terminal:
package com.github.kwhat.jnativehook is not visible
[ERROR]   (package com.github.kwhat.jnativehook is declared in the unnamed module, but module gamepad_tester does not read it)